# Error when using rule as a list index - { i, x[[i]] } /. i -> 5

Tags: syntax

I can't seem to use a rule to index a vector.

```
x = Range[10];
{ i, x[[i]] } /. i -> 5
```

I get the following error when evaluating the above code, even if the next cell shows the correct result:

```
Part::pspec: Part specification i is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [Trace](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html),

```
Trace[x = Range[10]; { i, x[[i]] } /. i -> 5]
```

we will see that the error comes from Mathematica trying to evaluate

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}[[i]]
```

As you pointed out, the error message is harmless in this case.  If you want Mathematica to substitute first, you can use [Hold](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) and [ReleaseHold](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReleaseHold.html):

```
x = Range[10];
ReleaseHold[Hold[{i, x[[i]]}] /. i -> 5]
```

which prevents the evaluation of `{i, x[[i]]}` until the `Hold` is released.  The output is the same, but now without the error message:

> {5,5}

Answer (score 11):

The existing answers explain why you are getting this error and how to get around it, and along the way explain something very useful about how evaluation works in Mathematica.

I would like to suggest some alternatives to get the output you want. Assume `x=Range[10]` as in your question.

Firstly, you could try setting `i` to be a local constant using `With`:

```
With[{i = 5}, {i, x[[i]]}]
```

> `{5, 5}`

Secondly, you could try using a pure function:

```
{#, x[[#]]} &@ 5
```

> `{5, 5}`

Whether you would prefer to use one of these alternative methods depends on the nature of the larger problem you are working on.

Answer (score 5):

Since this gives the correct answer in spite of the message, you could just use `Quiet`:

```
x = Range[10];
Quiet[{i, x[[i]]} /. i -> 5]
```

> ```
>  {5, 5}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

As stated several times this is the result of *Mathematica* evaluating `x[[i]]`, just as the error message told you.  Also, you can click the `>>` at the end of the message to get some more information.

You can do this operation in a number of ways, one of the best being `With` as Verbeia shows.
`With` only allows you to replace symbols however.  If you need to match patterns I suggest that you use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
x = Range[7, 11];

Unevaluated[ {3 + 3, x[[1]]} ] /. _Integer -> 5
```

> ```
> {10, 11}
> ```

Here both `3` and `1` were replaced with `5` because they match the pattern `_Integer` and this was done before evaluation (or you would get `{6, 7}`).