# Replace argument of delayed function before it evaluates

Tags: functions, evaluation, replacement, syntax, rule

How should I use replace so that

```
f[x_] := x^2
Replace[f[3], 3 -> 1]

OUT = 9
```

evaluates to 1, instead of 9?  This way, the replacement of the argument is done before the call to the function

Comment: `Replace[Hold@f[3], 3 -> 1, Infinity] // ReleaseHold`?

Comment: `ReplaceAll[Unevaluated[f[3]], 3 -> 1]`?

Comment: A slightly more complicated version of this question: [(25652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25652/121), and a related instance: [(30193)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30193/121).  Also see: [(25476)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25476/121)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(3105)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3105/121), [(91394)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91394/121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Activate@Replace[Inactive[f][3],3->1, Infinity]
```

> 1

or

```
Replace[Hold@f[3], 3 -> 1, Infinity] // ReleaseHold
```

> 1

Comment: We have had this very question several times before.  If you have time would you look for a duplicate?  *Edit: I found I couple of possible duplicates and linked them above.*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, could not find anything useful in the first 2-3 pages of search results with search terms `Replace` ,`Unevaluated` and `Inactive`. Btw, which search terms did you use to get the links you posted?

Comment: Thank you for looking!  I believe I was using the query `code:"/." code:unevaluated is:answer` but most of the time I feel like stumbling upon the right post is mostly blind luck; this is why I take so much time adding all the **Related:** links, because I often find things faster by following the network of connected posts.